# Issue translating curl PUT to Python requests: "Problems parsing JSON"

Tags: python, curl, github, python-requests, github-api

I'm looking to use the Python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library to [create a new file in a GitHub](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-a-file) repository. Entering the following in the command line works for me (replacing `LOGIN` and `TOKEN` as appropriate):

```
curl -X PUT -d '{"path": "testfile.txt", "message": "test", "content": "aGVsbG8y"}' https://api.github.com/repos/LOGIN/testrepo/contents/testfile.txt\?access_token\=TOKEN
```

But I keep running into the "Problems parsing JSON" error (status code 400) when attempting the same with requests:

```
data = {
    "message": "test",
    "content": "aGVsbG8y",
    "path": "testfile.txt"
}
url = "https://api.github.com/repos/LOGIN/testrepo/contents/testfile.txt?access_token={}".format(TOKEN)
response = requests.put(url, data=data)
```

Any hints as to what I'm doing differently? I've checked through the similar questions, but haven't found the right tweak. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because just passing a `data` parameter automatically sends your dictionary as form encoded parameters. Instead pass it as JSON

```
import json
data = {
    "message": "test",
    "content": "aGVsbG8y",
    "path": "testfile.txt"
}
url = "https://api.github.com/repos/LOGIN/testrepo/contents/testfile.txt?access_token={}".format(TOKEN)
response = requests.put(url, data=json.dumps(data))
```

Or if you're using at least version 2.4.2 you can do it like this:

```
response = requests.put(url, json=data)
```